# Transpose convolution math not working out

Tags: neural-network, convolution, implementation

I was reading [A Guide to Convolutional Arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285v1.pdf) to understand Transpose Convolution as it is cited in Keras and Theano documentation. I am having trouble understanding the following two statements :

***From section 4.1***

> Using this representation, the backward pass is easily obtained by
>   transposing C; in other words, the error is backpropagated by
>   multiplying the loss with C.T. This operation takes a 4-dimensional
>   vector as input and produces a 16-dimensional vector as output, and
>   its connectivity pattern is compatible with C by construction.

When I try this out in pytorch, the error is certainly **not equal** to multiplying with C.T

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

x = torch.arange(1, 17, dtype=torch.float).resize_(4, 4)
w = torch.rand(3, 3)
```

Convolve w and x

```
# Convert x into an "image" tensor with a single channel and part of a mini-batch of size 1
x1 = x.view(1, 1, 4, 4)
x1.requires_grad = True

# Convert w into a conv filter with a single input channel and a single output channel
w1 = w.view(1, 1, 3, 3)
w1.requires_grad = True

y1 = F.conv2d(x1, w1)
```

Backpropagate

```
y1.backward(torch.ones_like(y1))
x1.grad
```

Now create the C matrix as mentioned in the paper.

```
C = torch.zeros(4, 16, dtype=torch.float)

C[0, :3] = w[0]
C[0, 4:7] = w[1]
C[0, 8:11] = w[2]

C[1, 1:4] = w[0]
C[1, 5:8] = w[1]
C[1, 9:12] = w[2]

C[2, 4:7] = w[0]
C[2, 8:11] = w[1]
C[2, 12:15] = w[2]

C[3, 5:8] = w[0]
C[3, 9:12] = w[1]
C[3, 13:] = w[2]
```

Multiplying unrolled y1 by C.T will not equal to x1.grad.

`torch.mm(C.transpose(0, 1), y1.view(-1, 1)).view(4, 4)`

Where is my mis-understanding?

And the second statement that I have not been able to verify has been cited in a lot intuitive answers on StackExchange/Quora, etc.

***Section 4.3***

> Another way to obtain the result of a transposed convolution is to
>   apply an equivalent – but much less efficient – direct convolution.
>   The example described so far could be tackled by convolving a 3 × 3
>   kernel over a 2 × 2 input padded with a 2 × 2 border of zeros using
>   unit strides (i.e., i' = 2, k' = k, s' = 1 and p' = 2), as shown in
>   Figure 4.1. Notably, the kernel’s and stride’s sizes remain the same,
>   but the input of the transposed convolution is now zero padded.

When I try this in pytorch, the two results are not equivalent except for having the same shape.

```
F.conv_transpose2d(y1, w1)
F.conv2d(y1, w1, padding=2)
```

Again, I am pretty sure I am mis-understanding something, but can't put my finger on what.

Any help in clarifying these concepts greatly appreciated.

P.S: I have already taken a look at [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers?newreg=0000fa10e0d54fd3830a8f38b2a1bebc) and it does not answer my question.