# What is fractionally-strided convolution layer?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, convolution, convolutional-neural-network

In paper [Generating High-Quality Crowd Density Maps using Contextual Pyramid CNNs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00953), in Section 3.4, it said

> Since, the aim of this work is to estimate high-resolution and
>   high-quality density maps, F-CNN is constructed using a set of
>   convolutional and fractionally-strided convolutional layers. The set
>   of fractionally-strided convolutional layers help us to restore
>   details in the output density maps. The following structure is used
>   for F-CNN: CR(64,9)-CR(32,7)- TR(32)-CR(16,5)-TR(16)-C(1,1), where, C
>   is convolutional layer, R is ReLU layer, T is fractionally-strided
>   convolution layer and the first number inside every brace indicates
>   the number of filters while the second number indicates filter size.
>   Every fractionally-strided convolution layer increases the input
>   resolution by a factor of 2, thereby ensuring that the output
>   resolution is the same as that of input.

I would like to know the detail of **fractionally-strided convolution layer**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an  animation of fractionally-strided convolution (from this [github project](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic)):

[image]

where the dashed white cells are **zero** rows/columns padded between the input cells (blue). These animations are visualizations of the mathematical formulas from the article below:

[A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf)

Here is a quote from the article:

> Figure [..] helps understand what **fractional** strides involve: zeros
>   are inserted between input units, which makes the kernel move around
>   at a **slower** pace than with **unit** strides [footnote: doing so is
>   inefficient and real-world implementations avoid useless
>   multiplications by zero, but conceptually it is how the transpose of a
>   strided convolution can be thought of.]

---

Also, here is [a post on this site](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/6107/67328) asking "What are deconvolutional layers?" which is the same thing.

And here are two quotes from [a post by Paul-Louis Pröve](https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-convolutions-in-deep-learning-717013397f4d) on different types of convolutions:

> Transposed Convolutions (a.k.a. deconvolutions or fractionally strided
>   convolutions)

and

> Some sources use the name deconvolution, which is inappropriate
>   because it’s not a deconvolution [..] An actual deconvolution reverts the process of a convolution.