# Keras: DepthwiseConv3DTranspose or doing transposed Conv. with a Conv. layer

Tags: neural-network, keras, cnn, autoencoder

I am building an autoencoder for 3D images and would like to use Depthwise convolutions.
For the encoder, I found an 
 [implementation](https://github.com/alexandrosstergiou/keras-DepthwiseConv3D) of a depthwise 3D convolutional layer (DepthwiseConv3D).

For the decoder, I need a DepthwiseConv3DTranspose layer.

I did not find an implementation of this anywhere.
I [read](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers) that "a deconvolution layer performs also convolution".

This made me think: is it possible to choose parameters so that DepthwiseConv3D performs a transposed convolution?