# There are 2 figures explaining transposed convolution. Which one is correct?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, convolution

I have been struggling to understand transposed convolution. When I search for "transposed convolution", there are 2 figures explaining transposed convolution in which I think are not equivalent (or are they?).

[image: Transposed Convolution]

Figure 1. Transposed Convolution as explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/transposed-convolution-demystified-84ca81b4baba)

[image: Transposed Convolution]

Figure 2. Transposed Convolution as explained [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers)

Additionally, in Stanford's CS231N, transposed convolution was explained as in the Figure 1 ([here](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2016/winter1516_lecture13.pdf), slide 52). Meanwhile, another online lecture from TUM's DVL explained transposed convolution as in the Figure 2 ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdVSCtgHGF8&t=1102s)).